# Why is setting a form builder "readonly" in not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails Noob here.

I have the following code in my _form.html.erb:

```
 <%= f.time_select :slotTime,
  { :readonly => true, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 30} %>
```

When I view the page in my web browser the time selector drop downs are not disabled. I have used similar code for other text_fields and it works. Do you know why this might not work?

I have tried:

```
:readonly => true
```

and

```
:readonly => "readonly"
```

as is suggested by other questions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You want `:readonly` to end up as an HTML attribute and that makes it an HTML option; [HTML options go in the second Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_select) so I think you want this:

```
<%= f.time_select :slotTime,
  { :ampm => true, :minute_step => 30},
  { :readonly => true }
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Based on the documentation, it should... Odd. I tried restarting the server, different browser (currently testing in Chrome). Do I need to use `:disabled => true`? I thought that that prevented the update from happening properly.

Comment: Just checked that. For some strange reason, you need both options for the controls to be greyed out and the value untouched. Just disabling the form element gives strange updates. Making it readonly seems to prevent the value from changing, but leaves the controls active.

Comment: @JeffreyGuenther: [`readonly`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly) and [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) do different things, pick the attributes that match the behavior you're looking for.